# Best practice for testing customizations when hosted by Acumatica?

Tags: testing, acumatica

I have a customer that has a test and production company in their Acumatica instance (hosted by Acumatica).  I've made some customizations and need the customer to test but can't apply the changes to the test company without the code applying to the production company too.

So, I'm wondering what others are doing for having customers test changes before rolling them out to a production system?

As a partner/reseller, does Acumatica let us create test/playground instances in their cloud for situations like these, or do I need to set up this kind of environment on our own servers and let customers access a test/playground we set up for them?

Comment: it is recommended to have a separate instance for testing customizations. I believe acumatica does offer a sandbox instance but i don't the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your Acumatica contact to setup a [staging environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_environment#Staging) for you.

This is a usual request from partners and they'll know what to do.

Another good practice that reduces confusion when publishing customization is to pick a single company to publish all the customizations.